# Backbone/Marionette router event not firing when page is accessed

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette, backbone-routing

I am having trouble getting an event to fire on navigation to the page in my Backbone.js app.  First, the relevant code:

*users_app.js.coffee*

```
@Demo.module "UsersApp", (UsersApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

    class UsersApp.Router extends Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter
        appRoutes:
            "users" : "listUsers"

    UsersApp.API =
        listUsers: ->
            console.log "listUsers"

    App.addInitializer ->
        new UsersApp.Router
            controller: UsersApp.API
```

*app.js.coffee*

```
@Demo = do(Backbone, Marionette) ->

  App = new Marionette.Application

  App.on "initialize:before", (options) ->
    @currentUser = App.request "set:current:user", options.currentUser

  App.reqres.setHandler "get:current:user", ->
    App.currentUser

  App.addRegions
    headerRegion: "#header-region"
    mainRegion: "#main-region"
    footerRegion: "#footer-region"

  App.addInitializer ->
    App.module("HeaderApp").start()
    App.module("FooterApp").start()

  App.on "initialize:after", ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start

  App
```

I have tested it in the console, and I can call the function `listUsers` manually, with a simple `Demo.UsersApp.API.listUsers()`  However, `listUsers` is not firing on page load.  This implementation seems to also fall in line with the [Marionette documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.approuter.md#specify-a-controller)

Any thoughts?  Is there an easy way I can trigger the appRoutes event in the console to test it?

Comment: With "not firing" you mean that if you go to the address /index.html#users listUsers isn't called?

Comment: I mean that "listUsers" (the string) is not being outputted to the console.

Comment: Yes indeed, but are you hitting that route with your browser? because in your code is not set a default route.

Comment: I was manually typing it into the browser.  However, I ended up rolling back to the last version and rebuilding and now it works.  Thank God for version control.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify a controller in the appRouter:

```
{
    controller: UsersApp.API
}
```